# Manipulate serialize ajax data to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm struggling with reading post data from ajax post in my php code.
I'm neither an expert PHP nor Jquery,  I learn it a few weeks ago.  So sorry if I dont use yet all the terminology. I serialize data from ajax because I will have more field in my form. Here for the sake of clarity, I show only one field.
I'm trying to read each variable, for example  comment  in this case,
I simply try to print_r($_POST) and I got error.
I cannot see how to do,  probably a converting or syntax error.
I would appreciate any insights

**php file**

```
public function ajaxSave($post_id)
    {

    print_r($_POST);    

}
```

**jquery script**

```
$('body').on('click','#saveComment',function(e) {


            $("#comment-form").submit(function(e) {
                var postData = $(this).serialize();
                alert(postData);
                $.ajax( 
                {
                    url : "ajaxSave.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data : postData,
                    dataType:"json",
                    success:function(data)
                        {
                            alert('success');
                        },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                        {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                });
                e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
                });
            $("#comment-form").submit(); 
        });
```

**Form**

```
<input id="Comment_comment" type="text" name="Comment[comment]" maxlength="140" size="60">
```

**in Firebug**

in post tag, I have

```
Comment[comment]    mycomment
Comment[post_id]    16
```

Source

```
Comment%5Bcomment%5D=mycomment&Comment%5Bpost_id%5D=16
```

in HTML tag, I have

```
Array ( [Comment] => Array ( [comment] => for [post_id] => 16 ) )
```

Comment: You forgot to quote the url parameter

Comment: yes , thank you,  in my code it is coded so the php code is called,  I made a mistake in my retranscription @adeneo

Comment: but error it still there of course

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I hate capital letters in names, classes and IDs.  Like nails on a chalkboard.  Give us the PHP error

Comment: the print_r ($_POST) simply display  popup box with the word 'error'.  There is no particular coding number.  @Deryck

Comment: Are you sure you are calling this `ajaxSave` function and passing the serialized data to it?

Comment: Take that code out of the `ajaxSave()` function and just leave it global at the beginning of your PHP file and put a `return;` right after it for debugging and see if you get a different result.  Also look in your firebug/devtools for HTTP response(s) and post here

Comment: yes indeed.  I even save a trace to a file to be sure that code goes inside my php.  @ICanHasCheezburger    file = 'myblog.txt';
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    $current .= "  actionSave";
    file_put_contents($file, $current);

Comment: oh lol yeah you need to encode it too.  tell me if this helps: `echo json_encode($_POST);` - instead of print_r

Comment: @Deryck   yes it helps.  json_encode($_POST)  gives a json data

Comment: Did that solve it for you?

Comment: Yes I could use the result and continue what I was doing. Thank you @Deryck

Comment: Excellent glad to hear it.  I'm gonna post it in an answer so we can close the question out.

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting JSON back, but returning a print of the `$_POST` superglobal, and that's a parseError.

Remove the dataType and log the printout to the console to see it

```
$('body').on('click', '#saveComment', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#comment-form").trigger('submit');
});

$("#comment-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var postData = $(this).serialize();
    alert(postData);
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxSave.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

And don't bind the submit event inside a click event

Answer (score 0):

Replace `print_r($_POST);` with `echo json_encode($_POST);`